# Manage Exceptions in Junit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration. I have this junit:

```
@Test (expected = org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException.class)
    public void testInsertOrUpdateProductmiseria2() {

        List<ProductGroup> allProductGroups = productGroupDao.findAll();

        boolean test2miseria = true;

        for (ProductGroup productGroup : allProductGroups) {
            List<Productmiseria> productmiseria = miseriaDao.getmiseriaForProductGroup (productGroup.getId());

            if (productmiseria.size()==2) {


                Productmiseria miseria = new Productmiseria();
                miseria.setAdoptionDate(new Date());
                miseria.setExpirationDate(new Date());
                miseria.setCode("code");
                miseria.setProductGroup(productGroup);

                miseriaDao.saveOrUpdatemiseria(miseria);

                // can't reach this line. An exception has to be throwed by the TRIGGER TRG_miseria_ROWS  
                //ORA-20200: Product Group can not have more than 2 miserias
                test2miseria=false;

            }
        }
        Assert.isTrue(test2miseria);

    }
```

I've tried as well with **@Test (expected = java.sql.BatchUpdateException.class)**

But even the Exception is thrown the test is not passed

```
ORA-06512: at "DEVICES.TRG_CRITERIA_ROWS", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DEVICES.TRG_CRITERIA_ROWS'

(def.AbstractFlushingEventListener   301 ) Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:969)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1114)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:65)
    at com.tdk.env.devicelabel.dao.impl.CriteriaDaoImpl.getCriteriaForProductGroup(CriteriaDaoImpl.java:59)
    at com.tdk.env.devicelabel.dao.CriteriaDaoTest.testInsertOrUpdateProductCriteria2(CriteriaDaoTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.ConditionalTestCase.runBare(ConditionalTestCase.java:79)
    at org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.access$001(AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests$1.run(AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.java:179)
    at org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.runTest(AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.java:287)
    at org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.runTestTimed(AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.java:258)
    at org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.runBare(AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-20200: Product Group can not have more than 2 criterias
ORA-06512: at "DEVICES.TRG_CRITERIA_ROWS", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DEVICES.TRG_CRITERIA_ROWS'
```

Comment: as is a exception on execution time, maybe you need to use other different exception type, as generic Exception or RuntimeException, also you dont need the assert in your method, just make throw the exception

Comment: The method you are executing as a test doesn't appear in the stack trace of the exception. Is it possible that the exception occurs in a different test that is not expecting any exception?

Comment: @cralfaro It happens from the above test testInsertOrUpdateProductCriteria2 method line 57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test will not work, because the test stops when an exception is thrown. The `Assert.isTrue(test2miseria)` is not reached in this case.

Test methods are standard methods that are executed like any other method. E.g. they stop at the place where an exception is thrown. The only difference is that JUnit calls this method and does not report a test error if the exception is of the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

The thrown exception is `java.sql.BatchUpdateException`, you are expecting `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException`